# How to check if popup page is scrolled down fully Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a script to scrape images on [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g28970-d84078-Reviews-Hyatt_Regency_Washington_on_Capitol_Hill-Washington_DC_District_of_Columbia.html#/media/84078/?albumid=101&type=2&category=101) of hotels and I am able to iterate through all of them, my concern is whether to know I am finished scrolling within the popup window. I am unable to create a condition to break outside of my loop to then parse through all of the image urls and stays inside the loop infinitely. What should my if condition be in order to leave out of the loop? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
# import dependencies
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import re
import selenium
import io
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from _datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless=False

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/rishi/Downloads/chromedriver 3")
driver.maximize_window()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2} 
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

#open up website
driver.get(
    "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g28970-d84078-Reviews-Hyatt_Regency_Washington_on_Capitol_Hill-Washington_DC_District_of_Columbia.html#/media/84078/?albumid=101&type=2&category=101")

image_url = []

end = False
while not(end):
    old_image_length = len(image_url)
    #wait until element is found and then store all webelements into list
    images = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="media-viewer-dt-root-GalleryImageWithOverlay__galleryImage--1Drp0"]')))

    #iterate through visible images and add their url to list
    for index, image in enumerate(images):
        image_url.append(images[index].value_of_css_property("background-image"))

    new_image_length = len(image_url)

    #move to next visible images in the array which is the last one
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", images[-1])

    #wait one second
    time.sleep(1)

    #if the first and last image in the arrays are the same for visibility then get out
    if(old_image_length == new_image_length):
        end = True

#clean the list to provide clear links
for i in range(len(image_url)):
    start = image_url[i].find("url(\"") + len("url(\"")
    end = image_url[i].find("\")")
    print(image_url[i][start:end]) 

#print(image_url)
```

Comment: Repost? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321995/condition-to-check-if-selenium-is-done-scrolling-based-on-web-element

Answer (score 0):

@Rishiraj Kanugo You can check the visibility of last element in the popup to make sure that the popup is fully scrolled to the bottom.if(element.isVisible()){Syso("popup is fully scrolled down");}